# Having trouble finding an object that i need to click on

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find and click an element on a sidebar on the protonmail webpage but I'm having a hard time locating it.

[image]

```
openProtonTab = driver.execute_script("window.open('https://mail.protonmail.com/login','proton window')")
openProtonTab

pageSwitch = driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
pageSwitch

protonEmail = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
protonEmail.send_keys('botusername')

protonPass = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
protonPass.send_keys(botpassword)

loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_btn"]')
loginButton.click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ptSidebar'] and @id='pm_sidebar']/button']")))

compose = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pm_sidebar"]/button')
# didnt work either compose = driver.find_element_by_class_name('compose pm_button sidebar-btn-compose')
compose.click()
```

How can I find the compose element and click on it ?

Comment: Do you have a demo set of credentials for use?

Comment: Hard to say as I have to login first in order to see the HTML source, but I don't have an account. One thing that I can come up with is that you have to switch frames first to click on it.

Comment: Like switch frames from the main web page over to the sidebar ?

Comment: `//*[@id="pm_sidebar"]/button` is this xpath working in the browser dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a quick look, it seems xpath is not in correct format so, instead of `//*[@id="pm_sidebar"]/button` use `//*[@id='pm_sidebar']/button` it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Thank you ! I changed the code up after reading your answer and it worked.